# How to remove a listener before an event takes place?

Tags: extjs

My question is similar to this one: [How to prevent itemclick event on check change in Ext Js Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101853/how-to-prevent-itemclick-event-on-check-change-in-ext-js-tree).

However, it does not provide a solution for my problem. So, my question is: how can I remove a listener before an event takes place? The problem is that I have three listeners in my tree, and on `checkchange` I want to prevent the `itemclick` event. But everything executes in an unexpected order. The code is:

```
checkchange:function(node,check){                           
  alert("1");
},
itemclick:function(view,rec,item,index,eventObj){
  alert("2");
},
render:function(){
  Ext.getCmp('mytree').on('checkchange',function(node,check){
    alert("0");
    Ext.getCmp('mytree').removeListener('itemclick',this);
  });
}
```

When I check a node in my tree, I first see `alert(2)`, then `alert(1)` and only then `alert(0)`. So, the code which should remove the listener happens at the very end and I want the opposite.

**Edit:**

I do not want to completely remove the `itemclick` event. The more appropriate word is to "stop" an event, to prevent it from happening.

**Edit:**

The solution is to do e.getTarget() check inside the itemclick event. So, my code inside the `itemclick` event now looks like this:

```
itemclick:function(view, record, item, index, e, eOpts){
  if(e.getTarget('span',1,true)){
     // all other code which should take place in case
     // itemclick event does not come from checkbox element
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, it's important to understand the order events are fired:

1. `render`
2. `itemclick`
3. `checkchange`

Secondly, it's important to understand what's happening within the function you've defined for the `render` event.

What the code is doing is adding additional code to that which you've already defined for the `checkchange` function, so `checkchange` when it runs will alert `1` then `0` (what you are seeing). In addition, it will then remove the `itemclick` listener. This will mean that the second time you click a node, it should behave differently.

If you want to suppress the `itemclick` event immediately upon render, you should un-nest the `removeListener` call, thus:

```
render:function(){
  this.removeListener('itemclick',this).on('checkchange',function(node,check){
    alert("0");    
  });
}
```

Alternatively, you can simply remove the `itemclick` event listener itself.

If you want to change the way the `itemclick` event is handled, you can also intercept the event itself, using one of these methods:

```
itemclick:function(view,rec,item,index,eventObj){
  eventObj.preventDefault(); //or
  eventObj.stopPropagation(); //or
  eventObj.stop();
},
```

It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish, however.

Comment: What you are saying is absolutely reasonable. However, I tested my code and discovered that after the first check event the order of alerts remains the same. So, this "This will mean that the second time you click a node it should behave differently" turned out to be not right. Besides, I tested your code (first part which is most suitable for me) and got an error this.removeListener is undefined. It seems to me, that both you and me try to use this method in inappropriate way. By the way, I use Ext 4.1.

Comment: Try changing this.removeListener('itemclick',this) to this.removeListener('itemclick') - incidentally note the docs state it only works for events added using addListener. It seems what you really want is not to remove the itemclick event, but to either stop propogation or have nothing happen?

Comment: I simplified my code. I do not want to remove itemclick event complitelly, because it has much more code inside.

Comment: I changed to this.removeListener('itemclick') but still got the same error. And, by the way, I do not add listeners by addListener. So, is it possible to remove one of listeners in this case?

Comment: What I simply want is to halt itemclick event whenever I check one of my nodes.

Comment: And yes, you are right, I should say "stop propagation" instead of remove from the very first.

Comment: On the basis of itemclick( this, record, item, index, e, eOpts ), you need to capture the e object, and call e.preventDefault() or e.stopPropogation() - this will either stop the itemclick event itself or stop it and any related events, per the last section of the answer above

Comment: Now, we are closer to the solution. However, as I said before, itemclick event has much more code inside, so I do not want to stop it once and forever. I want itemclick event stay as it is now and I do not want checkchange event trigger it.

Comment: Note that itemclick triggers checkchange and not the other way around. If you click the item to change it, this will continue to be the case.

Comment: No, it is checkchange event that triggers itemclick first. It seems to me that in grid panel there is a bit different logic, when row select event causes checkchange to happen. But I have a treepanel.

Comment: You should change your question in that case, as you state alert 2 happens before 1, indicating itemclick is prior to checkchange. Please be completely specific in what you're after, as reading back there is some conflicting information making it hard to provide further help Im afraid

Comment: Thank you, Ergo! There is no any conflict in what I said. When I check a node it firstly triggers itemclick event and therefore alert 2 comes first and only after that alert 1 pops up. I finally got a solution at sencha forum. I got an advice to use e.getTarget() inside itemclick event to check whether this event comes from the checkbox or not. So, I just embrace all the code inside itemclick by if(e.getTarget('span',1,true)) and everything works great. Hope, this talk with you also will help someone. So, I mark it as a solution. Thanks!